# Unable to Edit top 200 rows in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, visual-studio-debugging

I am getting the following error - shown in the screenshot - when I click on "Edit Top 200 Rows" for my database table in SSMS. It's about just in time debugging but what should I do about that?

[image: Screenshot of error]

I have enabled Just In Time Debugging for Native, Script, Managed code in Visual Studio Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bad running of SSMS or a bad install.

1. close and run a new instance of SSMS

if this does not solve :

2. shutdown windows

if this does not solve :

3. reinstall SSMS